# Can I create a custom WordPress registration form?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to have in WordPress two kind of registration forms. The default one for let's say visitors users and a custom one for some more privileged users. How can I make the custom one? I especially need the part with the roles, the custom reg form will have another role for the users that will register to it. How can I do that? I think I need something like(it's just a fabulation, don't know the real functions from WordPress)

Example:

```
//the following variables will be a part of the form that will stand above this function
 add_user('$username','$mail','$location','$region','$role');
//where $role can be {1(subscribers),2(contrib.),3(authors),4(editor),5(admin)}
```

Can I do something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) to create your registration forms with the [User Registration](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/) add-on and specify custom user meta (including roles.) If you would like to create a custom form without a plugin, you should not attempt to add users directly to the database, instead you should use the `wp_create_user` function. From the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user):

> The wp_create_user function allows you to insert a new user into the
>   WordPress database. It uses the $wpdb class to escape the variable
>   values, preparing it for insertion into the database. Then the PHP
>   compact() function is used to create an array with these values. To
>   create a user with additional parameters, use wp_insert_user().

Comment: Any free option? Thanks anyway:)

Comment: @user3776900 You can use the above explanation to create your own form, it will just take a lot more effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a webform module in wordpress. Selected an existing form and customize the fields as per your requirement.